# App\PageList::coupon must return a relationship instance in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a `count()` from database but I am getting an error.
I am trying to find how many N are in is_ordered field.

My Model look like:

```
public function coupon()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id')
                ->where('is_ordered','N')->count();
}
```

and my blade view:

```
 <p>{{optional($value->coupon)->is_ordered}}</p>
```

I am unable to find a solution.
your help will be highly appreciated!

```
public function pageListHere()
{
    $list = PageList::all();
    return view('page-list',compact('list'));
}

              class PageList extends Model
   {
       protected $table = 'page_master';


     protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];

public function particulars()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Sale','user_id','business_id');
}
public function coupon()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id');
}


}
```

Comment: can i see your controller  ? and whats the error you getting ?

Comment: here is my controller i edit in my question

Comment: what error did you got

Comment: i tried in your way but i got error App\PageList::couponCount must return a relationship instance

Comment: how i can do that by defining another function?

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it this way.
Leave your first function coupon like this:

```
    public function coupon()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id')->where('is_ordered','N');
    }
```

And then you can have a second function as so:

```
public function couponCount()
{
    return $this->coupon->count(); 
}
```

After that you can use it in blade on your variable like so: $coupon->couponCount();

Comment: and it says undefined variable $coupon

Comment: any more suggestions pls?

Answer (score 0):

Your code and what you want is little bit confusing. try this:

**PageList.php**

```
public function coupon()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function pageListHere()
{ 
    $list = PageList::all();
    return view('page-list',['list'=>$list]);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($list as  $listItem)
 <p>{{$listItem->coupon()->where('is_ordered','N')->count()}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: since you put hasOne in coupon function you only have one coupon for each page

Comment: sorry i did not show you the whole model i edit my whole model in my question

Comment: there 2 relation ship in my model

Comment: when i tried your code it says is_ordered column not found this field is under app/PageCoupon

Comment: OK few question: 1. in which table  `is_ordered` at ? 2. for one page only have one PageCoupon ?

Comment: is_ordered is in ( App\PageCoupon) and i have made relation with page_master as you can see in my model  2- for one page there can multiple page coupon thats why i want count();

Comment: <p>{{optional($value->coupon)->is_ordered}} from this i am getting two N but i want this in digit like this (2)

Comment: and for this i am using count(); and i get error App\PageList::coupon must return a relationship instance in laravel 5.5

Comment: when i try in my model like this public function coupon()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PageCoupon','page_id','business_id')->where('is_ordered','N')->count();
    } it gives me error

Comment: can we chat i am really confused in this

Comment: it says htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: Here is error <p>{{$listItem->coupon()->where('is_ordered','N')->count()}}</p>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168344/discussion-between-supun-praneeth-and-shahzad1122).